# Need smooth scrolling to a div when anchor tag with id is clicked instead of jumping to that div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
<div id="slider">
    <div id="pro1"></div>
    <div id="pro2"></div>
    <div id="pro3"></div>
</div>

<div id="thumb">
    <a href="#pro1"> <img id="tpro1" src="projects/tpro5.jpg" style="height: 100%;"></a>
    <a href="#pro2"> <img id="tpro2" src="projects/tpro5.jpg" style="height: 100%;"></a>
    <a href="#pro3"> <img id="tpro3" src="projects/tpro5.jpg" style="height: 100%;"></a>
</div>
```

This is the code i worked  with, when i click on the link it is just jumping to that `div` so i want some animated horizontal scroll to show that `div`

thanks

Comment: This has been asked so many times: [jQuery scroll To Element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6677035/1456376). You can adopt the answer here to also scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did u solved the problem already?

look, i tried this and it worked for me so, i think it can work for u ;)
Dont even need  the element *< a >*

```
$("#thethingyougonnaclick").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:$("#theelementidtoscroll").offset().top}, 500);
});
```